# CMFCPropertyGridCtrl option drop down problem

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a CMFCPropertyGridCtrl some of the CMFCPropertyGridProperty items have options. This allows the user to select a value from a drop down list. The problem is when the user click to select a value the wait cursor show up. I have not found a way to fix this. Does anyone have some insight for this problem?

Comment: Do you have a Change function for the control. Is it possible to provide the code?

Comment: I had the problem before any change functions were added to the code.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this functionality is build in MFC:

`void CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::OnClickButton(CPoint point)
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);
    ASSERT_VALID(m_pSel);
    if (m_pSel->OnUpdateValue())
    {
        CString strPrevVal = m_pSel->FormatProperty();
        CWaitCursor wait;
        m_pSel->OnClickButton(point);
        if (strPrevVal != m_pSel->FormatProperty())
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(m_pSel);
        }
    }
}`

Unfortunately the only way change the behavior is change MFC's source code and rebuild MFC.

Comment: When I made a standalone project the behavior is difference. When I click on a drop down the wait cursor flash then would be the non wait cursor when the drop down was visible. So there must be some override method in our project that is messing us up.

Comment: @dlb: I had the same problem, but I didn't found solution. Seems like that for standalone application wait cursor appears but for a short period of time.